# Identify points in a distance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, computational-complexity

The problem I try to solve is as follows. I have two sets of points $A$ and $B$ ($n(A) > n(B)$).

In set $A$ there is a subset $A^{cor} \subset A$ that corresponds roughly with set $B$ only by a scale transformation, so for two elements in $B$, $b_i$ and $b_j$, there are two corresponding elements in $A^{cor}$, $a_k$ and $a_l$ for which $D(b_i, b_j) - \alpha D(a_k, a_l) < \epsilon$. In which $\alpha$ is constant across all combinations.

The question is whether there is an algorithm that can extract the subset $A^{cor}$ from $A$ given $B$ that scales a bit gracefully. Doing this in brute-force will probably not be fast enough ($n(A)$ can be up to 5000). Is there such an algorithm?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ known? Are these points in Euclidean space (and is this scale transformation linear) or are $A, B$ general metric spaces?

Comment: $\alpha$ is unknown. We are talking about straight-forward points in 2d space (2d integer coordinates to be exact).

Comment: We can assume no rotation or skew or anything. Just scale.

Comment: One not-so-gracefull solution is to create a huge matrix dividing every element in distance matrix of A and distance matrix of B and make a clustering of the matrix elements. But that matrix can grow several Gigs

Comment: You might try looking at ratios $\frac {b_j - b_i}{b_k - b_i}$ among the $x$-coordinates of $B$, and look for similar ratios among the $x$-coordinates of $A$. Use the matches to narrow your search. Do the same thing on the $y$ coordinates. Not sure how efficient the idea is, though.